# Script that sends to clipboard pastes, and clicks one line at a time

Tags: bash

I am inserting data into a database and I want to do it faster.
So I have this example text:

```
ME7X59Q2S
MVGBJKUC6
VWMAU5FVV
KBCZYF864
TXTLURSAQ
8GNCEFAYR
QW3MEUMK5
U3BWX7LQP
BV47XFENE
```

I want to copy one line at a time and paste it and activate MOUSE1.

So I want to send one line at a time from the txt to the clipboard, paste it into the text box, and activate MOUSE1 to click the button in order to insert it in the database.

Is this possible in any way? I was trying to develop a batch file but I'm having trouble with the one line at a time part.

The mouse part is also making this difficult for me.

THanks

Comment: Could you add more information to your question via the [edit] button? As of right now it is unclear what you're asking. You have also tagged the question with [c] and [bash] but it is unclear what either of those languages have to do with your question.

Comment: Please ask an [\[ mcve \]](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JonnyHenly : Thanks for  that :) . I do know that stuff, but the way I have put it is kind of a personal touch to that. but if somebody suggest me that it is not good practice, I am ready to change it though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do              # Read line for line
  xclip -sel pri <<< "$line"             # This adds a trailing newline
  # printf "%s" "$line" | xclip -sel pri # This doesn't
  read </dev/tty                         # Wait for enter
done < my_file.txt                       # Input file
```

This will copy each line in `my_file.txt` to your primary clipboard (Middle mouse button can paste), each time you press enter a new line is copied.

Comment: It is great that you deciphered what the op had in mind ;)

Comment: @sjsam I'm not sure though. I put it here since I might be on the right track.

Comment: If that works, I really should bookmark it for another discussion "linux/unix is not for desktops" :-)